# How to overwrite server-side forced download window?

Tags: firefox, download, hyperlink

When clicking at a link to a file, three things can happen by default (depending on the configuration of your browser and also of the server):

- **a)** the file gets opened in the browser
- **b)** a download window gets opened, where you can choose to open the file with a specific program or to save it locally
- **c)** a download window gets opened, which only asks if you want to save the file locally

My question is about **c)**, which, I assume, is triggered by a server-side configuration (specific HTTP header resp. MIME type). See the example below.

Is there a way to "overwrite" this behaviour, i.e., to get the usual download window **b)** instead?

#### Example

On [this (German) page](http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Abmahnungen-wegen-Redtube-Porno-Streaming-erste-juristische-Gegenwehr-2064084.html) there is an external [link to a PDF](http://www.lg-koeln.nrw.de/Presse/Pressemitteilungen/10_12_2013---Abmahnungen-_The-Archive_.pdf), which triggers this download window:

[image: Iceweasel screenshot of download window]

Translation: Do you want to save this file? <kbd>Cancel</kbd> <kbd>Save file</kbd>

As you can see, it doesn’t offer to open this file with a specific program.

---

Update: [sahmeepee suggested a solution](https://superuser.com/a/688216/151741) that works for "known" MIME types, i.e., you have to find a different download for a file of the same MIME type, so that this MIME type can be added to the mentionend download settings list. **So I’m still looking for an "on the fly" way of overwriting such forced downloads.**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the download action for PDF files as per the Firefox guide here:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file

> At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button and then
>   select Options
>
> Select the Applications panel.
>
> The Applications panel will display. Select the type of file for which
>   you want to change the default action.
>
> The Action column will give you a drop-down menu, with options on
>   action to take, whenever you click that type of file.

The specific example in their screenshot is for PDF files.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this suggestion. I didn’t have the entry, so I had to download a different PDF file (so that the usual download window opens) and choose the option "Open with …"; this added "PDF" to the list. After that, I could change the setting for PDF, so now this forced download window is gone. -- I updated my answer and keep this question open to see if there might be a specific way to overwrite those forced downloads on the fly, instead. If not, I’ll accept your answer.